# How to find the key for the minimum value in jsonb column of postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I need to find the key of the minimum value in a jsonb object,I have found out minimum value, need to find the key of the same in the same query.

Query I am using

```
SELECT id,min((arr ->> 2)::numeric) AS custom_value 
FROM ( 
   SELECT id, jdoc
   FROM table, 
        jsonb_each(column1) d (key, jdoc)
   ) sub,
     jsonb_each(jdoc) doc (key, arr) 
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.
The `left join ... on 1=1` is for keeping IDs with empty json

```
select      t.id
           ,j.key
           ,j.value

from                            mytable t

            left join lateral  (select      j.key,j.value 
                                from        jsonb_each(column1) as j 
                                order by    j.value 
                                limit       1
                                ) j

            on 1=1
```